# Can I upload an image into stack.imgur.com and not post the question?

Tags: support, imgur

We can upload an image into *stack.imgur.com* when to open a new post and publish the question, and I know how to do it. Can I upload an image into stack.imgur.com (not imgur.com) and not post question?

Comment: Paste the image into the answer (or question) editor, upload it, then copy the link and clear the editor.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to add images to comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85501/282094)   see also:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75491/282094   https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370334/282094

Comment: Well - I'd much rather people do that than post non questions/answers just to post images

Comment: The question ***here*** may be if it is possible to ***use the Stack Exchange question interface as a way to upload/host an image on [Imgur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imgur)*** (without actually submitting the Stack Exchange question). The [second duplicate covers that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145994/how-can-i-upload-an-image-to-use-it-in-a-comment/146035#146035).